# How to renumber a series into parallel sets

Tags: r, time-series, factors

I'm working in R. I have a dataframe, `df` that looks like this:

```
> str(exp)
'data.frame':   691200 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ groupname: Factor w/ 8 levels "rowA","rowB",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ location : Factor w/ 96 levels "c1","c10","c11",..: 1 2 3 4 12 23 34 45 56 67 ...
 $ starttime: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ inadist  : num  0 0.2 0 0.2 0.6 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ smldist  : num  0 2.1 0 1.8 1.2 0 0 0 0 3.3 ...
 $ lardist  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.3 ...
 $ fPhase   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Light","Dark": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ fCycle   : Factor w/ 6 levels "predark","Cycle 1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I'd like to add another column, `timepoint`, that gives the `starttime` relative to the beginning of the `fCycle` it is in.  So `starttime=1801` would be `timepoint=1` for `fCycle='Cycle 1'`.

What is the best way to create `df$timepoint`?

ETA toy dataset:

```
starttime fCycle timepoint
1         1      1
2         1      2
3         1      3
4         1      4
5         2      1
6         2      2
7         2      3
8         2      4
9         3      1
10        3      2
11        3      3
12        4      1
13        4      2
14        4      3
15        5      1
16        5      2
17        6      1
18        6      2
19        6      3
20        6      4
```

Comment: You might want to clarify what you want to do using a toy data set , as explained [in this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Right now I have no idea what starttime is, and the only thing I can think of is `df$timepoint <- 1` (as I assume the starttime is equal for every observation within a cycle).

Comment: @Joris Meys: I've added some example data.  The idea is that I should be able to compare measurements at the same offset from the beginning of any cycle.

Comment: Just to clarify, what if fCycle[c(21,22)]=c(1,1)?  Is the timepoint now (1,2)?  Or are cycles monotonically increasing?

Comment: @Iterator: at the moment the dataframe is sorted by groupname, then location, then starttime. So there are 96 rows where starttime=0, then 96 where starttime=1, etc. The fCycles were assigned using ranges of starttimes, e.g. predark is where starttime<=1800. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @dnagirl : It doesn't. If you have two observations with the same starttime in the same fCycle, do they have the same timepoint or different ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `rle` with `sequence`. Here is some sample code. Is the output what you were looking for?

```
require(plyr)

mydf = data.frame(
  starttime = 1:20,
  fCycle    = c(rep(1:3, each = 4), rep(4:5, each = 3), rep(6, 2))
)

# sort data in increasing order of cycle and starttime
mydf = arrange(mydf, fCycle, starttime)

mydf = transform(mydf, timepoint = sequence(rle(fCycle)$lengths))
```

NOTE: In the light of the fact that there could be identical starttimes within the same fCycle, here is an alternate approach using `rank` and `ddply`

```
# treat same starttimes in an fcycle identically
ddply(mydf, .(fCycle), transform, timepoint = rank(starttime, ties = 'min'))

# treat same starttimes in an fcycle using average
ddply(mydf, .(fCycle), transform, timepoint = rank(starttime, ties = 'average'))
```

Comment: +1 Good use of `sequence`.  Just a note: a `,` seems to be missing at the end of the the `starttime` declaration.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't fit the original data. There you have multiple starttimes that have the same value, see also the comments. Your code would result in erroneous timepoints.

Comment: @Joris. i dont understand your comment. i was just using the toy data provided by the OP.

Comment: @Ramnath : See the comments on OP's question. Arrange does indeed only take care of one part.

Comment: @Joris: see my edited solution which will take care of a range of possibilities and i think is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

This is an outline of a solution, because I'm not quite clear on what you're asking.  It seems like you're asking for something derived from run length encoding (RLE), which can begin via the `rle()` function.

1. The `rle()` output will give the lengths of each run (assign this `lengths`).
2. The offsets where each run occurs can be calculated (via `cumsum(c(1,lengths))`).
3. These can then be `rep` (repeated) a sufficient # of times (i.e. for each item in the run).
4. For each position (`1:n`) simply subtract the location of the start of the run.

EDIT: There's no need to use `rep` in step 3.  It can be a lookup to the lengths.